# Gracefully Close application With Yes Response

Tags: powershell

We have application and when we close it, it ask to change the status to offline. When we hit Yes, application get closed and its status changed. I tried to close the application with powershell using below code.

Get-Process 'Application' |? { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null }

But it prompt for status change diaolog box to hit yes to close. I want to pass this yes to close directly without any prompt for response.

Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure this will be possible, unless you can simulate mouse movements/clicks or send keys to the application to click the yes button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using "Kill" method (see [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill)) or combining both, would help?
Or you could try "[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%F4")" (see [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait?view=netcore-3.1)